# django - passing information when redirecting after POST

Tags: django, forms, redirect-after-post

I have a simple form, that when submitted redirects to a success page.

I want to be able to use the data that was submitted in the previous step, in my success page.

As far as I know, you can't pass POST data when redirecting, so how do you achieve this?

At the moment I'm having to just directly return the success page from the same URL, but this causes the dreaded resubmission of data when refreshed.

Is using `request.session` the only way to go?

Comment: Any mechanism that allows you to persist the data between requests will do (since this is in the end what you ask for). Session is probably the simplest, but definitely not the only way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can:

1. Pass the data (either full data or just id to object) in request.session
2. Redirect with something like ?id=[id] in URL - where [id] points to your object.

**Update:**

Regarding pt. 1 above, I meant that you could do (in POST handler):

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.create(...)
request.session['my_object_id'] = my_object.id
```

Or you could try passing the whole object (it should work but I'm not 100% certain):

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.create(...)
request.session['my_object'] = my_object
```

Comment: Which object are you referring to? Is there an object somewhere that contains the POST data that can be assessed?

Comment: Yes, it's named request.POST.data

Comment: But when I redirect, the page wont have access to the POST data will it?

Answer (score 8):

I do this all the time, no need for a session object. It is a very common pattern [POST-redirect-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Typically what I do is:

1. Have a view with object list and a form to post data
2. Posting successfully to that form saves the data and generates a redirect to the object detail view

This way you save upon POST and redirect after saving.

An example view, assuming a model of *thingies*:

```
def all_thingies(request, **kwargs):
    if request.POST:
        form = ThingieForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            thingie = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(thingie.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = ThingieForm()
    return object_list(request, 
                       queryset = Thingie.objects.all().order_by('-id'),
                       template_name = 'app/thingie-list.html',
                       extra_context = { 'form': form },
                       paginate_by = 10)
```

Comment: +1: I haven't figured out that Acorn might just want to redirect to object detail page :-)

Comment: The thing is, my page isn't submitting to a database, it's sending a message off into the internet, so there's no relevant page for me to redirect to.

Comment: @Acorn Well, instead of saving do the send, and then redirect to the succes page you mentioned in your question

Comment: The question was regarding how to carry through data from the submission into the new page. I assume using session is the way to go then.

Comment: Yup, if you do not persist the data in any way, session is a solution